# capture text events on iOS textfield with flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ios, keypress

I am using flash cs5.5 and have the following code for a textfield

txt.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , key_up);
txt.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , key_down);
txt.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT , key_input);

I am building for iOS (using AIR) but none of these events fire up on the iPhone. On the simulator it works ok.
How can I capture these events on iOS? I have tried both with textfield and TLFTextField.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using StageText? In addition to the events you listed, you get:

- SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_ACTIVATE
- SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_ACTIVATING
- SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE (be careful with this one if you're using AIR 3.2 - can cause a crash)

Some of the other benefits:

- You can set the keyboard type (e.g., SoftKeyboardType.EMAIL)
- You can set the label for the return key on the soft keyboard (e.g., "Search")
- You get iOS's built-in auto-correct
- You can set iOS's built-in auto-capitalize (e.g., AutoCapitalize.WORD)

The downside is that StageText is more difficult to work with than the other textfield types. However, an Adobe employee – Christian Cantrell – created a wrapper class for StageText called NativeText which is designed to simplify things. It's currently on GitHub, works with Flash CS, and has been forked a few times to fix some bugs and add missing features:

[NativeText on GitHub](https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample)